# PHP: Gettext problems

Tags: php, locale, gettext

I can't seem to get gettext working, here.

I'm using MAMP Pro and `phpinfo();` says that gettext is enabled.

I followed this tutorial: http://zez.org/article/articleview/42/1/

1. I have my strings declared in my code like this: `_('test string');`
2. Then I ran `xgettest -L PHP test.php`, which generated my `messages.po` file.
3. I opened this file in [poedit](http://www.poedit.net/) and translated my strings, then saved the file, which made a `messages.mo` file.
4. I took both the `.po` and `.mo` files and moved them to `[webroot]/locale/es/LC_MESSAGES/` (in this case, my translation was Spanish)
5. In my code, I set the following:

   `$lang = $_SESSION['lang']; // available to all views that include this file`

   `putenv('LC_ALL='.$lang);`

   `bindtextdomain('messages','./locale');`

   `textdomain('messages');`

   ... where `$_SESSION['lang']` I can easily toggle between `en` and `es`.
6. I reload my page, then click on my link that toggles to `es`, but my strings are still showing up as the English versions and not the Spanish versions. Toggling back to `en` shows no change; it's always the English versions.

I get no error message anywhere so I'm a bit lost as to why I'm having this problem. Can anyone give me some guidance/help? Did I miss something?

Comment: Try to hardcode "es", then we'll know it is a problem with i18n or just a session messup.

Comment: Or try to modify the english translation.

Comment: "es" hardcoded effects no change.

Comment: Okay, I do see the changes when I modify the English translation. Now what?

Comment: @neezer: So, you uses one of the translations (the english), but you mixed up smg in your code.

Comment: @erenon Not sure I understood your last comment; could you clarify?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems as though the problem may be with poedit. Originally, all my Spanish translations I had marked as "fuzzy". If I remove "fuzzy" from them, they show up on my webpage like they should.

I don't think this is normal behavoir, but hey, at least it works.

Answer (score 1):

You also need to install the corresponding language files on your server as so:

```
cat /usr/share/i18n/SUPPORTED |grep -i "es_ES" > /var/lib/locales/supported.d/es
cat /usr/share/i18n/SUPPORTED |grep -i "nl_NL" > /var/lib/locales/supported.d/nl
cat /usr/share/i18n/SUPPORTED |grep -i "de_DE" > /var/lib/locales/supported.d/de
```

Now you installed the languages Spanish, Dutch and German. When finished, run **dpkg-reconfigure locales** and you are done. =)

Comment: The OP is using MAMP PRO, so is on OS X. `dpkg-reconfigure` isn't going to work there.

Comment: It's cute that you are using the case insensitive switch to grep a case intact search string.